# Maesurability of function $\mathbb R\ni t \mapsto P(X>t)$

Tags: probability

Let $(\Omega, S, P)$ be a probability space and $X$ be a measurable function on this space.
Is a function $\mathbb R\ni t \mapsto P(X>t)$ Lebesgue or Borel measurable?

Answer (score 0):

$P(X>t)=1-P(X< t)-P(X=t)=1-F(t)-P(X=t)$.
The distribution function $F$ is nondecreasing, which is measurable. I don't sure about $t\mapsto P(X=t)$.

Comment: The function $t \mapsto P(X>t)$ is decreasing (possibly not strictly).  So it is certainly Borel measurable.  It is also Riemann integrable.  Similarly $t \mapsto P(x \ge t)$ is Borel measurable.  So the difference $t \mapsto P(X=t)$ is Borel measurable.